# If/elif statement only works when command is inserted between semicolon and then

Tags: bash

I'm seeing strange behaviour with a bash script I'm writing at the moment.

When running a if/elif statement, the "then" portion is only triggering when I put a command between the semicolon and then.

The below code is the original, where the elif does not trigger

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Checking all policies have test cases in directory: $1"
cd $1 #$1 is the first argument passed to this script, in this case it is the output of the command "pwd"
set +e

for policy in *.sentinel; do
    test_dir=$(echo $policy | awk -F. '{print $1}')
    if [ ! -d "test/$test_dir" ]; then
        echo "No test cases for policy $policy in subfolder $test_dir"
    else
        cd test/$test_dir
        if ! ls fail.hcl >/dev/null || ! ls pass.hcl >/dev/null; then
            echo "Missing at least one of fail*.hcl, pass*.hcl or mock*.sentinel in for policy $policy in subfolder $test_dir"
        elif egrep -ir --include=*.sentinel "tfconfig/v2" .
        echo hello
        then
            cp ../../../sentinel_mocks/mock-tfconfig-v2.sentinel ./test-mock-tfconfig-pass-v2.sentinel
        fi
        cd ../../
    fi
done
```

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Checking all policies have test cases in directory: $1"
cd $1 #$1 is the first argument passed to this script, in this case it is the output of the command "pwd"
set +e

for policy in *.sentinel; do
    test_dir=$(echo $policy | awk -F. '{print $1}')
    if [ ! -d "test/$test_dir" ]; then
        echo "No test cases for policy $policy in subfolder $test_dir"
    else
        cd test/$test_dir
        if ! ls fail.hcl >/dev/null || ! ls pass.hcl >/dev/null; then
            echo "Missing at least one of fail*.hcl, pass*.hcl or mock*.sentinel in for policy $policy in subfolder $test_dir"
        elif egrep -ir --include=*.sentinel "tfconfig/v2" .
        echo hello        # if this line isn't here then the below does not run
        then
            cp ../../../sentinel_mocks/mock-tfconfig-v2.sentinel ./test-mock-tfconfig-pass-v2.sentinel
        fi
        cd ../../
    fi
done
```

The folder structure is as follows, the script is being ran from policy_set_1 with the command -  ./test.sh .

```
policy_set_1
├── authorised_vpc.sentinel
└── test
    ├── authorised_vpc
    │   ├── fail.hcl
    │   ├── mock-tfconfig-fail-v2.sentinel
    │   ├── mock-tfconfig-pass-v2.sentinel
    │   ├── pass.hcl
    │   └── sentinel.hcl
```

I've never seen this behaviour before so any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like `egrep` exits with non-zero status, probably because `tfconfig/v2` isn't found in any sentinel file. Please confirm this by running `egrep -ir --include=*.sentinel "tfconfig/v2" .; echo $?` and pasting the exit code here. If the output is not 0, then your observed behavior is expected.

Comment: Why are you using `ls` to test for the existence of a file? `if ! [ -f fail.hcl ] || ! [ -f pass.hcl ]; then`

Comment: @chepner, good question. It was a script I adapted. But if there is a better way to do it (like your suggestion) then I will use that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realised the egrep command I was using was looking in the wrong folder.
I amended it to the following and it worked:

```
egrep -ir --include=*.sentinel "tfconfig/v2" ../../$policy
```